# How do you call a party where people drink a lot?

Tags: vocabulary

What do you call a party where people drink a lot?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you be satisfied with the answer "We have no special term for it"? In fact, can you give examples of an English term with a similar connotation?

Comment: Hello. In English it is called a banger.

Comment: Where is “banger” used this way? The OED doesn't know about it.

Comment: @Gio: Per piacere, ripristina la risposta su “bisboccia”. Mi sembra pertinente, e sarebbe anche il caso di dare nuova vita a “bisboccia” al di fuori della locuzione “fare bisboccia”. Dopo tutto, di per sé significa proprio «Baldoria, allegra e abbondante mangiata e bevuta, fatta in compagnia» [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bisboccia/), che risponde esattamente all'OP. Da vedere anche i [sinonimi di “bisboccia”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bisboccia_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/).

Comment: @DaG As far as I can tell it is reported only in the Urban Dictionary, and not as first meaning. I also never heard of it in the four years I've been living in the US (but I am not a party animal). I think it is some kind of college-student slang.

Comment: @DaG - It is clear that "fare bisboccia" is not the expression OP is looking for.

Comment: @Gio - I believe that a mention of *bisboccia* is useful, at least as a reference for future visitors of this site. If you do not intend to recover it, do you mind if I write a new answer about it?

Comment: @DaG - please do.

Comment: Pqcv, neanche il Green's Dictionary of Slang, piuttosto ben fatto, contempla questo significato: https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=banger (@DenisNardin)

Comment: "bisboccia" oppure "baldoria", credo

Answer (score 4):

A term with a meaning near to what you are looking for is ***bisboccia***: «Baldoria, allegra e abbondante mangiata e bevuta, fatta in compagnia» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bisboccia/)) or, as Zingarelli defines it, «allegra riunione per mangiare e bere abbondantemente».

Now it is rarely used, and mostly in the verbal phrase *far bisboccia*, but a search for it in Google Books shows that it is still quite vital, even in contemporary texts: we find several “*compagni di bisboccia*”, “*comincia una strepitosa bisboccia*” (in a translation of Kerouac), “*Una bisboccia come tutte quelle del tropico, con una componente di gioia e una di incertezza*” (in a translation of García Márquez), a definition of *bisboccia* as “drinking binge” (in a [handbook about Italian](https://books.google.it/books?id=AM3UBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&dq=%22bisboccia%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bisboccia%22&f=false)) and more.

Also consider some of the terms offered by dictionaries as synonyms of *bisboccia*: *baldoria*, *gozzoviglia*, *bagordo*, *crapula*, *festino*, *stravizio*, all pointing out to unordered eating and drinking.

Answer (score 3):

Culturally, binge drinking isn't a thing in Italy.

Young people tend to get more drunk in recent years, and everyone drinks, but alcohol-centric parties are not something so widespread yet to have its own name (not even a slang one).

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MacmAwvJo8g) can maybe explain it better.

Bisboccia is a more goliardic term that indicates "noise" more than "alcohol".

There are expressions like "scorrerà vino/birra a fiumi" to indicate that a lot of drinks will be there, but it's a more generic use (you could say it of any liquid... say soda).

Comment: You are forgetting about the northeast. We do drink a lot and do have drinking parties, which are sometimes called "baccanali", as a joke

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give it a negative connotation, you can say *festino* (in this case *festino a base di alcol*)

Answer (score -2):

There are basically two ways to call a party where people drink.
The most used term is just "festa". For example:

> Stasera c'è una festa sul lungomare.

We can also say "serata" which is literally "evening" but it's like a 'slang' to refer to a party where there will be alchol and dancing people! You can use it in the same way you can use "festa":

> Stasera c'è una serata sul lungomare.

It makes perfectly sense

Comment: -1: Neither of these terms apply specifically to parties where drinking is particularly prominent. In fact *festa* is used for any form of celebration (from religious feasts, to birthday parties for children, to some local fairs...) and *serata* refers to any evening event (for example a *serata di moda* is a fashion party, which can involve alcohol but not necessarily)

Comment: You're right @DenisNardin, if he asked for a party where people specifically  drink, my answer's not right. But I'd say we have no term to call a party where there's much alchol. _Festa_ and _serata_ are the terms we use to call it but they could actually mean other things besides a party where there's alchol and people drink.

Comment: The fact remains that if you invite me to a *festa sul lungomare* or a *serata sul lungomare* I would not expect to find particularly large quantities of alcohol there (ok, that also depends on the age of the people involved :))

Comment: currently I am considering the expression "festa alcolica"

Comment: Mmm @cornejo I've never heard of "festa alcolica". We aren't used to specify whether there will be alchol or not. Here, in my city at least, "serata" means there will be alchol. We would use "festa" otherwise.

Comment: And if you say "serata", does it mean that people drink a lot?

Comment: Usually yes, unless I say "serata" followed by something else :))

Comment: I wouldn't understand *serata* as meaning that there will be lots of alcohol, but just as a party, slightly more highbrow than another kind of *festa*: it might involve classical music, a reading, a fashion event, whatever.

Comment: I too would consider a *serata* somewhere you go to hang out. It might involve alcohol, but not particularly so.

Comment: I said "serata" may not involve alcohol in fact! I just said that's how we call a party where there's alcohol. I don't know why. That's how we mean that, here. Even if I do know that "serata" doesn't mean specifically a party with much alcohol

Comment: "serata" by itself doesn't necessarily imply drinking, but "serata alcolica" is an expression I've heard often...